# How to create sections for parsed Data in objective c

Tags: objective-c, sections

I have parsed data which I put in tableview alphabetically. Alphabetical order is based on the last name of a person. Now I need to add index bar and sections. What I am creating is kind of address book. This is the code I am using to put the parsed data in the cell `label.text = [arrayOfTitle objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];`

This is the code through which I placed index bar and section titles on the tableview:

```
-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [[self arrayOfNames] count];

}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 26;
}



-(NSArray*)sectionIndexTitlesForTableView:(UITableView *)tableView

{

    return [[UILocalizedIndexedCollation currentCollation] sectionIndexTitles];
}




- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)aTableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    if ([self.arrayOfNames objectAtIndex:section] ) {
        return [[[UILocalizedIndexedCollation currentCollation] sectionTitles]
                objectAtIndex:section];
    }

    return nil;

}

@end
```

I know how to create sections out of plist file but since here I just have an array of parsed data, I am having a hard time to break it into sections. 
Thank you for your help.